# How can I properly fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?

Tags: debian

I get errors like:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/file1.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/file2.list:1
```

from `apt` family tools.  I want to know how to *properly* get rid of these warnings.

Now, I know the cause, and I know the classic answer: edit the files.
I reject this answer, as it misses the point of `sources.list.d/`.
The `*.d/` directories exist so that you can **install** into them.
Therefore, you should not edit the results.
And if you do edit them, things will break if the file you didn't edit gets removed.

So: how do I fix this warning *without* editing the files?
(Or do I have to patch `apt`?)

What I'm hoping for is an APT configuration variable,
perhaps something I can drop into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.

Comment: It’s just a warning, you can ignore it if you don’t want to fix the root cause.

Comment: @StephenKitt Its a screwy popup in `aptitude`.  Not a simple ignore.  Further, it happens a LOT.  Like when I expand a grouping.